# Из 2 папок с одинаковыми файлами выбрать 1 файл

Tags: c#, файловая-система

Есть 2 папки, в этих папках файлы с именами: 20200620.txt, файлы приходят с интервалом 1 час в обе папки сразу. Бывают сбои и в 1 из папок файл может не попасть.

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FileSystemWatcher mainFolder = new FileSystemWatcher(path: @"C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\Test1", filter: "*.txt")
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
            };

            mainFolder.Created += OnCreateMainFile;
            mainFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


            FileSystemWatcher spareFolder = new FileSystemWatcher(path: @"C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\Test2", filter: "*.txt")
            {
                NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName
            };

            spareFolder.Created += OnCreateSpareFile;
            spareFolder.EnableRaisingEvents = true;




        }

        private static void OnCreateSpareFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType} in Spare Folder");
        }

        private static void OnCreateMainFile(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType} in Main Folder");

        }
```

Как мне выбрать из пришедших файлов 1 и с ним работать, а если не пришел во 2 папку файл вообще, тогда работать с 1 файлом?

Comment: Имя каждого последующего файла другое или всегда имя одинаковое?

Comment: Сделаю тоже замечание, что и к ответу: вотчеры сделаны локальными переменными. Не будут ли они собраны сборщиком мусора? Имеется в виду полноценный сценарий, где код не ограничен одним классом.

Comment: @aepot Имя каждого последующего файла другое.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Приложение MVVM WPF так что не будет собрано, данный код нужен для демонстрации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, решением тут может быть некая задержка перед чтением данных, то есть нечто такое:

```
private const string firstPath = @"D:\Test\1";
private const string secondPath = @"D:\Test\2";
private static readonly List<string> tempPath = new List<string>();
private static CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Test")
    {
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        IncludeSubdirectories = true
    };
    watcher.Created += OnCreated;

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static async void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource?.Cancel();
    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tempPath.Add(e.FullPath);
    await DelayRead(cancellationToken: tokenSource.Token);
}

private async static Task DelayRead(int delay = 1000, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        var file = tempPath.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(firstPath)) ?? tempPath.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(secondPath));
        Console.WriteLine($"Считываем: {file}");
        tempPath.Clear();
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Задача отменена");
    }
}
```

Поясняю:

- Мы все `FileSystemWatcher` (кстати, в вашем случае можно обойтись одним, просто указать ему `IncludeSubdirectories`) подписываем на одно событие, у меня это `OnCreated`.
- В этом событие мы

  - Отменяем (если есть) старое ожидание.
  - Создаем токен отмены для нового ожидания.
  - Добавляем полученный путь нового файла во временный список.
  - Запускаем задачу чтения, которая должна после ожидания прочитать файл.
- Далее сама задача ожидания, это простой `Task`, который имеет `Task.Delay()` с указанным временем и токеном отмены.

  - Если токен подал команду на отмену, то задача выдаст `TaskCanceledException`, который мы обрабатываем как надо и не выполняем дальше логику.
  - В переменную `file` я забираю по примитивной логике (которую вам наверно надо будет расширить под свои нужды) из той самой временной коллекции путь сначала тот, который соответствует первой директории и если он `NULL`, то беру 2-ую директорию.
  - Полученный путь вывожу на экран (у вас тут чтение и другая логика).
  - Очищаю временный список.

В итоге будет работать так:

- Запускаем ожидание при появление нового файла.
- Если ожидание все еще идет и появился новый файл, то начинаем его по новой.
- Если в течении указанного времени не было создано новых файлов, то берем тот, который подходит под нашу логику.

Я тут не стал сильно нагружать пример лишним, но в комментариях правильно заметили, что тут идет работа с несколькими потоками, а значит стоит себя обезопасить в этом плане. Моя задача была лишь показать задумку, которая могла бы решить данную задачу, а уж как дальше ее примерять уже оставлю на вас.

А кстати, если вам без разницы какой файл открывать первым (главное открыть), то можно тогда вовсе обойтись одним обработчиком, где вы делаете простой флаг, некая `bool` переменная, которая будет говорить начали вы чтение файла или нет и тогда в момент появления нового файла вы просто берете первый пришедший, читаете его, флаг ставите на `true` (тем самым исключив повторного запуска чтения из файла со 2-й директории) и по окончанию чтения вы флаг возвращаете обратно на `false`. Ну либо запоминайте имя последнего прочитанного файла. То есть нечто такое (набросал на глаз, не проверял):

```
static string lastFile;
private static void OnCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(e.FullPath);
    if (lastFile != fileName)
    {
        lastFile = fileName;
        Console.WriteLine($"Считываем: {e.FullPath}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо @EvgeniyZ . Ваше решение действительно работает отлично.

Answer (score -1):

Интересная задачка, убил время, но вроде решение есть, код нужно допиливать, он в тестовом варианте.

- Приходят два файла в две разные папки.
- Приоритет всегда у первой    папки.

Вот код с комментами:

```
class FileFindFolder
{
    private bool f1 = false; // чек работы с первой папкой
    private string _firstPath = ""; // первый путь
    private string _secondPath = ""; // второй путь

    /// <summary>
    /// Конструкт класса FileFindFolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_firstPath">Первый путь до папки</param>
    /// <param name="_secondPath">Второй путь до папки</param>
    public FileFindFolder(string _firstPath, string _secondPath) 
    {
        this._firstPath = _firstPath;
        this._secondPath = _secondPath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Запуск работы программы
    /// </summary>
    public  void Run()
    {
        LookFileFirst();
        LookFileSecond();
        Console.WriteLine("Что бы закончить, нажмите любую кнопку");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Слежка за первой папкой
    /// </summary>
    private  void LookFileFirst()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); // можно упростить создание экземпляра
        
            _watcher.Path = _firstPath; 
            _watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
            _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; 
            _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName; 
            _watcher.Renamed += OnChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Слежка за второй папкой
    /// </summary>
    private  void LookFileSecond()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

                _watcher.Path = _secondPath;
                _watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
                _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
                _watcher.Renamed += OnChanged2;
            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Реакция на приход в первую папку файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private  void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Выполняю задачу с первой папкой"); 
        f1 = true;
        // Что то сделалось
        // присвоить f1 = false

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Реакция на приход во вторую папку файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void OnChanged2(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
       if (!f1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выполняю задачу с второй папкой");
        } else { Console.WriteLine("Приоритет работы с файлом из первой папки"); }
      
    }
}
```

Фото выполнения работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код на гите: [тык](https://github.com/jlovenpk1/ForTraining/blob/master/ForTraining/StackOverflow/OpenFileInFolder/FileFindFolder.cs)

Comment: События вотчеров происходят в другом потоке. Поэтому доступ к `f1` нужно защитить тем или иным образом. И название переменной нужно дать говорящее.

Comment: Нужно выбрать один файл из двух. А в вашем сценарии могут обработаться оба, если второй чуть позже придёт, когда обработка первого уже завершена. Недостаточно булевой переменной, нужна проверка времени.

Comment: Ещё одно замечание. Вотчеры сделаны локальными переменными. Не будут ли они собраны сборщиком мусора? Не уверен, нужно подумать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я показал пример рабочего варианта :)
А дальше уже под нужды можно и допилить

Comment: Нет, нерабочий. Он не отвечает на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тогда жду рабочий вариант )